# various videotag questions (html5)

Tags: youtube-api, html5-video

if I have a video tag in html5, I can respond to the canplay event, or the canplaythrough event.  The first tells you when the video is ready to play, and the second tells you that it is not only ready to play, but the whole video has loaded on your PC.  Does this make a difference when you try to set the 'currenttime" to near the end of the video?  Would it work in both cases, even if there was a delay in the second case?

Also: I read that youtube is making an html5 way of playing their videos.  Does this mean that they use iframes, and use a set of commands that are similar to the videotag commands?  Or does it mean that they really are using the HTML5 video tag?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In order to accurately set the current time, the HTML5 video API does not need to have the whole video loaded ... it just has to know how long the video is. So listening for either event should work, but you could also listen for the loadedmetadata event, which is triggered slightly earlier.

Youtube has had beta support for true html5 playback for some time; you can opt into their beta here:

https://www.youtube.com/html5

As a developer, you can also force html5 playback when embedding an iframe by appending html5=1 to the end of the query string of the iframe's src url. However, there will still be flash fallback when HTML5 isn't supported (i.e. IE8 and below) or when the video has ads.